# JUnit @Rule ExpectedException

Tags: java, junit, error-handling

I have been trying to use the JUnit expected Exception to validate my own exceptions for an application, however whenever I try to use this the compiler complains that there is an uncaught exception.

```
@Rule public ExpectedException invalidInputException1= ExpectedException.none();
@Test (expected = WarehouseException.class)
public void testRunProblem_withInvalidInput1() {
    System.out.println("Warehouse Problem: "+INVALID_INPUT_EXAMPLE1);
    Warehouse instance = new Warehouse();
    instance.setDefault();
    invalidInputException1.expect(WarehouseException.class);
    invalidInputException1.expectMessage("ERROR - INVALID INPUT: "+INVALID_INPUT_EXAMPLE1+Errors.INVALID_INPUT_TEXT_EMPTY);


    throw new WarehouseException("");
}
```

The problem occurs on `throw new WarehouseException("")` where it just complains the following:

[image]

Further debate on the fact that the method should handle the exception over the JUnit Javadocs led me to attempt what was asked, the result is as follows:

[image]

[image]

All i can think is wrong here is that Java is handling the exception BEFORE JUnit can access it to evaluate it and thereby ignoring the fact that i expect the exception during the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExpectedException` does not free you from the need to declare (or catch, but in this case, you want to declare) that Exception if it is a "checked" Exception (in other words, if it is not extending `RuntimeException`). In other words, your method must look like this...

```
public void testRunProblem_withInvalidInput1() throws WarehouseException {
...
}
```

`ExpectedException` only handles your test case ("do not fail, if WarehouseException is thrown, but only if it is NOT thrown, etc."), etc., but the method itself must be correct Java and if you throw a *checked Exception*, you must either catch or declare it, that's the Java requirement. In this case, you want to declare it - since it will be thrown and then caught by the `ExceptedException` (which is effectively wrapped around your test case method, that's how those test rules work).

`@Test` annotated methods can have any `throws` declaration you want, this is totally ok. Without using an `ExpectedException` `TestRule` or `@Test(expected=...)`, any Exception that is actually thrown will lead to the test method failing with an error, of course. But `throws` just declares which Exceptions **can** be thrown, it does not mean that they HAVE to be thrown.

**Edit after discussion**: Another point was, that the `ExpectedException` rule and `@Test(expected=...)` do not play nice with each other and should not be used together - only one of them, otherwise one of them (the rule) will fail.

Comment: I do not believe that this statement is correct, if you look at the existing examples of use for this framework they do not include this, the Javadocs for expectedexception do not state this either: [link](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) and indeed i tried doing this initially when i had the issue, and it does not provide correct functionality and fails the unit test.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the framework. Just plain java. If you throw a checked exception, you must either catch or declare it, see the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html . End of story. No framework will change that. As in your case, you don't want to catch it (because that would make the ExpectedException useless), you must declare it. You can believe that if you want or not, but that's also what your error message is telling you. That requirement comes from the compiler, long before JUnit even starts.

Comment: And if I had to guess why your unit test failed before... You are checking for a message `"ERROR - INVALID INPUT: "+INVALID_INPUT_EXAMPLE1+Errors.INVALID_INPUT_TEXT_EMPTY` but are throwing `new WarehouseException("")`. Sure that this is equal? Fix your code, if the old error reappears, you can ask it in a new question, we'll fix that one, too, promised ;-)

Comment: Shaetz I can only tell you what i see and i know this will not work, i did try it and i know that its not the message thats failing it, i commented that out to ensure i was checking just the exception being found.

Comment: Never the less, I have now done this and it STILL does not work, oddly. That said i may bring you a new problem if you can solve the original one first.

Comment: And how does it not work? What's the new error message? Unfortunately, at the moment, my mind reading skills are all busy trying to find out a certain phone number... ;-) One error at a time...

Comment: Dear me i would point to the updated OP, but then i suppose i better actually lead you to it? Admittedly I probably should have specified that i was placing it in there, so slight apologies but a response in less than a minute didnt give me _that much_ time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106149/discussion-between-bradleykins-and-florian-schaetz).

Comment: Discussion Found that the offending code was: using both Rule and Test() at the same time, thanks to Shaetz for finding this bit!

Comment: And it's right there, should have seen it earlier, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `throws WarehouseException` in method declaration:

```
public void testRunProblem_withInvalidInput1() throws WarehouseException {
```

Because this method can throw checked exception you must caught it in this method o throw up to stack of invocation, despite the fact that this only test method.

Comment: As replied above, i do not think this answer is correct.

Comment: As Florian Schaetz wrote it's about Java compiler not about JUnit framework.